# Videojs currentTime() function not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video.js

I'm using the videojs currentTime() function to jump to a specific time in the video. I have it working in Chrome, but Firefox (16) doesn't seem to respond (other api functions like play/pause do work in FF).

Videojs api docs: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md#currenttimeseconds--type-integer-or-float

```
_V_("video").ready(function(){
    var vidplayer = this;       
});

$(function() {
    $('#time').click(function() {
        seconds = $(this).text();
        vidplayer.currentTime(seconds);
        vidplayer.play();
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you preloading the video? I deleted my original answer for now while I work on this, but there are two important points from it: ready() tells you when the *player* is ready, not that the video is loaded, and there's a bug in FF pertaining to load(). currentTime in FF works, but only when you've already pressed play (which actually loads the video).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Yes I am preloading (preload is set to 'auto'). Does that remove the need for load()?

As for FF, currentTime() does work to get the time. But currentTime(seconds) (to set the time) doesn't seem to have an effect even after play() has been called.

Comment: No worries, now I want to figure it out just to know. Yes, that removes the need for load() except for on mobile. On FF v17 I'm able to use `currentTime()` to seek to a position as long as I've called `play()` first. I was also able to do this in 16 before I upgraded. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No not getting any errors. It just returns the video object. I'm also in FF17.